# How do I configure an Entity Framework interceptor in an aspnet vnext config.json file?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In a web config file, I would do this:

```xml
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>

<interceptors>
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="C:\tmp\DataAccessLogOutput.txt" />
    </parameters>
  </interceptor>
</interceptors>
</entityFramework>
```

But how do I do it in vnext's config.json:

```js
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": { 
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-Cupcake-a652ca1c-0d92-4155-ad46-bfb68bb538ee;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
        }
    },
    "EntityFramework": {
        "ApplicationDbContext": {
            "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really unfortunate that most of this vnext stuff is so poorly documented. I keep finding questions like this just totally unanswered and really no documentation anywhere on the web. It's a let down. Because I truly think this json stuff can be better than web.config, but without the documentation it is utterly useless. </rant>

Comment: @RobertNoack that's kind of the curse of beta software.

Comment: @Josh: any luck in finding the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the functionality does not exist yet in EF7. It's on the backlog but does not seem to be implemented yet.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1629

Comment: Anyone aware of any updates to this?  Because this question is very old and I have a specific use case in mind I asked a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660746/can-i-configure-an-interceptor-yet-in-entityframework-core